# Is it possible to migrate Data from iPhone to any Desktop SQL Data Base?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite, core-data

I'm developing an app that stores data in the iPhone, but I need to know if it's possible to export the data (as an entities, tables, .txt or xls) to a desktop because I need the data to be readable on my Computer OR do I need to create a web site to do it?
By the way.. I'm still not sure what method is more effective for this kind of app, Core Data or SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data on the desktop and iOS are identical.  You can stand up a SQLite file created on either on the other with no issues.  In these situations it is highly recommended (I would say necessary) to use the same data model in both applications.